# can anyone help me with this problem?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational and by $f(x) = 1 / a$ if $a$ is the first digit not
null in its decimal representation. Prove that $f$ is measurable and find the value of its integral.

First of all, sorry for the way I have written it, it is the first time that I use this website. I had thought the following:

We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ has zero measure because it is a countable set. On the other hand we have that if $f, g$ are measurable functions with $f (x) = g (x)$ in $X \setminus B$, being $B$ a set of zero measure, then $f (x) = g (x)$ in almost everything and its integrals are equal.

Then we will have to define a function $g$ in $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ so that if $f$ is
Lebesgue measurable, $g$ is also measurable, and the value of its integral is the same at $X$.

I have thought that a sequence $g_k (x)$ should be defined that is the sum of simple functions (with characteristic functions) and measurable, but I don't know how to continue from there because I can't find the interval.

Comment: As a hint, can you formalize the intuition of "About $\frac{1}{9}$ of all irrational numbers have their first non-zero digit as being $1$"?  Similarly "About $\frac{1}{9}$ of all irrational numbers have their first non-zero digit as being $2$"

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: sorry, i have almost edited this post. its my first one and I am a little bit lost

Comment: @jj2: Your question is now, in my opinion well written. Also, you may want to lear how to write mathematical formulae [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Every number $x\in(0,1)$ has a unique decimal expansion
$$
x=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{a_n(x)}{10^n}
$$
where $a_n\in\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$, and $\sum_na_n=\infty$.

For any $a\in\{1,\ldots,9\}$, the numbers in $\big[\frac{a}{10},\frac{a+1}{10}\big)$, $\big[\frac{a}{10^2},\frac{a+1}{10^2}\big),\ldots,$ etc have $f(x)=1/a$

Comment: thanks a lot. I have done it and I think the solution may be 1/(9a)

Comment: @jj2: I think the value of the integral is $\sum^9_{a=1}\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{9}\sum^9_{a=1}\frac{1}{a}$

Comment: I do not get the same result :(

Comment: @jj2: You did (in a way) but you only got the result for a particular digit ($a$) You need to add over all possible digits, (there are nine of them)

Comment: aaaah then I think I just have to add your last comment to what I have done